# can you set an image.src attribute to point to another image's bitmap data?

Tags: html, image, src

In html is there a way to set an image's src directly from another image's data, rather than using the url (ie NOT `image1.src = image2.src`)

cheers.

UPDATE
After looking at the restrictions of data uri s I have decided that its not the way forward.
I will probably have to draw onto a canvas instead.

thanks for all your help

Comment: No, but you can do it in `Javascript`, as it's DOM manipulation.

Comment: Are you trying to accomplish this when the page loads or is it triggered at some point after the page is loaded?

Comment: You can do this with the base64 data instead of the url. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images

Comment: I have a single image on display, and a hidden preloaded list. on user interaction the displayed image is swapped for one off the list. When I change using src to src the latency is too great. I know I could do this with canvas, but then I'd have to write more code to make it responsive.

Comment: @Mguimard cheers, so I would have to load them in as base64 rather than using image?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your needs, but if you already have loaded an image and just want to get the base64 you can do this as described in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript

Comment: @mguimard Thanks, since this solution requires canvas I figure I might as well just use the canvas directly.

Answer (score 0):

I am now using a div and setting the background-image css on user interaction.
I originally solved the issue using canvas, but this is over complicated and not optimal for OSX devices.